# Can the sockets gem be used locally in environment that doesn't require a 'rack'?

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, sprockets

**My question is for ruby (not rails):** since the sprockets gem is for 'rack' based applications (handling HTTP requests, etc), is it appropriate to use for local applications that are not necessarily on a server?

I am very interested in using javascript inside of ruby.  In my exploration, there are plenty of great gems out there that provide ways to do this.  The majority of them have been for rails, which is obviously a rack based application that uses sprockets-rails.

Looks like the best option for dealing with javascript in a ruby application is the [sprockets gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sprockets).  Wanted to do a sanity check.  Am I on track? Thanks!

Assuming that sprockets [MUST have HTTP requests to work](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#accessing-assets), can it still be used in ruby app? Maybe the app must have an internet connection to work?

EDIT: After doing some more reading, it looks like I am trying to run a node.js app that has node.js dependencies via ruby.

**Small Goal:**

Invoke a javascript function with ruby.  For example, say there's a javascript function such as...

```
function something() {
  return "F.U.B.A.R.";
}
```

Possible to use that javascript function in ruby by loading the file then calling the function? Such as...

```
def foobar?(str)
  return true if str == something()
end
```

**Big Goal:**

Run node.js function via ruby command.  (If you can run it in the command line, why can't you invoke it with ruby?)

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: hi @intale, I updated my question to provide more explanation.

Comment: It is quite unclear, why do you want to do that. If you need to run the js code in ruby script - you might want to use therubyracer ( https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer ) gem. Sprockets gem is responsible for completely another thing - assets management.

Comment: The reason is I am trying to run a javascript file that has dependencies. I originally looked into therubyracer but I kept getting `module not defined` errors.  I figured that was a dependency problem...

Comment: And you want to, e.g., merge all js files into one using sprockets and then run it?

Comment: @intale, exactly. The endstate of what I am trying to do is [here](https://github.com/m8ss/franc).  This is executing a bash command and is obviously a hack and not good...

Comment: That won't do. `therubyracer` just provides you js interpreter in ruby. It is not supposed to work with nodejs or nodejs packages. So if you would like to run nodejs packages from ruby - you should use bash commands. You may also check https://github.com/rails/execjs gem. It provides interface for external js runtime.